# Firebase Messaging can't send background messages Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

I have got the following code in my index.ts

```
const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Order!',
        body: you sold a ${order.day} for ${order.time},
      },
    }; 
    return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
```

And this in my Flutter:

```
 messaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
    );
  }
  static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    var data = message['data'] ?? message;
    print(data);
    // Or do other work.
  }
```

While the `onMessage`  part works perfectly finely, onLaunch and onResume don't work. Netierh does the onBackgroundMessage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onBackgroundMessage` method and `flutter_local_notifications` package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications
[image]

you are checking data not notification

```
 static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    var data = message['notification'] ?? message;
    print(data);
    // Or do other work.
  }
```

Comment: If i'm sending from Android and receiving on IOS, shouldn't it work?

Comment: you are checking data not notification, i edited my post check it

Comment: @IBMR also you can't get print(data) when your app is terminated

Comment: Then how do I check if the notification has been received?

Comment: you can check logcat and if you want to show notification you can use flutter local notification package

Comment: and make sure to check message['notification'] not message['data'] because you are sending with notification, check your payload you will understand @IBMR